How to read power data on teltonika trb145 gateway - PHP + Socket?
Good morning,
I am facing difficulty obtaining energy data from meters that are connected to teltonika trb145 gateways via RS485.
I'm using the OverIP feature, available on the equipment in client mode:
enter image description here
Feature documentation: https://wiki.teltonika-networks.com/view/Serial_OverIP_communication_between_Server_and_Client
I created my server application, it receives connection from the gateway, but does not send data, or maybe
I have to request the records, but I was not successful.
Part of my code below:
<?php

if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
    echo 'Should be used only in command line interface';
    return;
}

require 'vendor/

autoload.php';
require './logger.php';

ob_implicit_flush();


use ModbusTcpClient\Packet\ErrorResponse;
use ModbusTcpClient\Packet\ModbusApplicationHeader;
use ModbusTcpClient\Packet\ModbusFunction\ReadHoldingRegistersRequest;
use ModbusTcpClient\Packet\ModbusFunction\ReadHoldingRegistersResponse;
use ModbusTcpClient\Packet\ModbusPacket;
use ModbusTcpClient\Packet\RequestFactory;
use ModbusTcpClient\Utils\Packet;
use ModbusTcpClient\Utils\Types;
use React\Socket\SocketServer;
use ModbusTcpClient\Network\BinaryStreamConnection;
use ModbusTcpClient\Packet\ModbusFunction\ReadInputRegistersRequest;
use ModbusTcpClient\Packet\ModbusFunction\ReadInputRegistersResponse;
use ModbusTcpClient\Packet\ResponseFactory;


// Install: 'composer require react/socket:^1.6'
// OPTIONAL: install PHP extension ('ev', 'event' or 'uv') for better support of event loop within PHP.

$address = getenv('MODBUS_SERVER_BIND_ADDRESS') ?: '0.0.0.0';
$port = getenv('MODBUS_SERVER_PORT') ?: '4000';

$logger = new EchoLogger();

$loop = React\EventLoop\Loop::get();
$socket = new SocketServer("{$address}:{$port}", [], $loop);

$socket->on('connection', function (React\Socket\ConnectionInterface $conn) use ($logger, $loop) {
    $logger->debug($conn->getRemoteAddress() . ": connected: ");
    $address_remote = explodeAddress($conn->getRemoteAddress());
 
    // buffer for received bytes for that connection
    $conn->write("Server ready:{}\n");
    $receivedData = b'';

    $conn->on('data', function ($data) use ($conn, $logger, &$receivedData) {
        //$logger->debug($data);
        $logger->debug($conn->getRemoteAddress() . ": received: " . unpack('H*', $data)[1]);

I ran the code shared above, I receive a connection from the gateway, but the data is not sent or I am unable to connect to the gateway IP and receive the data from the modbus registers that I need.

... I receive a connection from the gateway ... or ... I am unable to connect to the gateway IP... Well, which one is it?

My endpoint, server socket, receives connection from the gateway, but I cannot connect to this IP + port of the Teltonika equipment to request a Modbus request. @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Your question is still confusing (please pick one mode for the TRB, server or client, and focus on that). Assuming client mode (as per the screenshot), then how are you determining that the Server ready{}\n is not sent? (if the meters are expecting Modbus then they would just ignore that string). I note that you are importing ModbusTCP packages, but not RtuConverter (you will need to send Modbus RTU packets if connecting in this way).

Thank you for your reply here, @Brits
I am really inexperienced when it comes to using the Modbus protocol.
So what you are telling me is:
1 - Do I need to send a packet and perform the conversion to Modbus RTU as below?
$tcpPacket = new ReadHoldingRegistersRequest($startAddress, $quantity, $slaveId);
$rtuPacket = RtuConverter::toRtu($tcpPacket);
$connection->connect()->send($rtuPacket);
2 - I am only able to access the gateway remotely through port 80, is this normal? Shouldn't it be a standard (502)?

I don't use PHP so based my comment on a quick look at this example - but yes, with your current setup you need to send Modbus RTU packets over TCP (the packets differ from ModbusTCP packets). Port 502 is for Modbus TCP, and you are not currently using this. "remotely through port 80" this will depend on the device configuration (personally I'd suggest this as a simpler option for you).
